# Validation is not working in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am creating an angular form in angular 6. Now the problem is it take me directly to next component even after applying validation.Validations are not working for any of Input.
Following is FormComponent.Html code and typescript code is given below it.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h3>Please fill following information</h3>
            <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }"
                    />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }"
                    />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }"
                    />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="contact" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.contact.errors }"
                    />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.contact.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.contact.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="f.contact.errors.required">Invalid contact</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }"
                    />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" (click)="showPassword()"></span>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ReEnter-Password</label>
                    <input type="password" formControlName="retypePassword" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.retypePassword.errors }"
                    />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" (click)="showConfirmPassword()"></span>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.retypePassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.retypePassword.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="f.retypePassword.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
                        <div *ngIf="f.retypePassword" !="f.password">Password must be same</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Following is FormComponent.ts .There are no errors coming but still validation not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-form',
templateUrl: './form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
registerForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
data;
   myPassword = "password";
  confirmPassword = "password";

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private route: Router) { }
 showPassword() {
  if (this.myPassword == "text") {
  this.myPassword = "password";
  }
  else {
  this.myPassword = "text";
  }
  }
   showConfirmPassword() {
  if (this.confirmPassword == "text") {
  this.confirmPassword = "password";
  }
  else {
   this.confirmPassword = "text";
   }
 }


ngOnInit() {
this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  retypePassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  contact: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
});

if (this.data) {
  this.registerForm.patchValue({
    firstName: this.data.firstName,
    lastName: this.data.lastName,
    email: this.data.email,
    contact: this.data.contact,
    password: this.data.password,
    retypePassword: this.data.retypePassword

  });
  }

 }


get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
this.route.navigate(["/show-details"])

// stop here if form is invalid
if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
  return;
}

localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value));
}

}
```

Comment: You're navigating away before checking whether the form is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  // put this line AFTER the invalid check:
  // this.route.navigate(["/show-details"]);

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  // HERE:
  this.route.navigate(["/show-details"]);

  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the form status before navigating. ts file can be modified as below.

```
onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
   return;
 }else {
   this.route.navigate(["/show-details"]);
   localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value));
 }
}
```

You can even block user to submit form without proper form data. You can use button to get enable only for valid input.

```
 <button type="button" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">Register</button>
```